# Spring util properties with scope

Tags: java, spring

If i create a properties file like below :

```
    <util:properties id="appProps" location="classpath:app-config.properties" scope="singleton"/>
```

in my application code as class level object

```
    private static Properties props=null;
```

In my method:

```
    props=(Properties)context.getBean("appProps").
```

if i make 100 calls to this method ,how many objects will create. if it creates signle object ,is any useful to make props object as static?

Regards,

Raju

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if i make 100 calls to this method ,how many objects will create.

Because the `scope` is `singleton`, the call to

```
context.getBean("appProps")
```

will always return the same object reference each time.

> if it creates signle object ,is any useful to make props object as
>   static?

That is up to you and your requirements, but honestly don't. Just **inject** an instance of the class that contains it anywhere you need it.